# How are neurons in deeper layers capable of making more complex decisions than neurons in shallower/earlier layers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, perceptron

I'm brand new to ML and am reading the online book at http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com.

In the [first chapter](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#perceptrons) the author describes a single perceptron using a Cheese Festival example. Basically he illustrates an example of a perceptron trying to decide whether or not to go to a Cheese Festival on the upcoming weekend. The perceptron has 3 inputs (a weather factor, a social factor and transportation factor). And while I completely understand 100% the author's "Cheese Festival" example for a **single perceptron**, I don't understand the next (seemingly non-sequitur) conclusion that he draws, where he evolves the example to contain multiple perceptrons organized into 2 layers:

> "What about the perceptrons in the second layer? Each of those perceptrons is making a decision by weighing up the results from the first layer of decision-making. In this way a perceptron in the second layer can make a decision at a more complex and more abstract level than perceptrons in the first layer....In this way, a many-layer network of perceptrons can engage in sophisticated decision making."

**What I don't understand is: Why are perceptrons in the 2nd layer able to "make a decision at a more complex and more abstract level" than their counterparts in the 1st layer?**

Can someone provide an example, perhaps using the Cheese Festival example already started by this author? What is an example of a more complex/abstract decision that could be made by a perceptron in Layer 2?

---

### Example

[image]

The top of the diagram (above) shows the decision-making perceptron behind the author's Cheese Festival example. The lone perceptron takes in 3 inputs/factors: weather, social and transportation factors. From these it calculates/determines whether one should go to the Cheese Festival or not.

The bottom of the diagram above (that is, underneath the horizontal line) illustrates perfectly where my mental hangup is. Here, we have 3 neurons in Layer 1 feeding into a single Layer 2 node:

- A *"Should I go to the Cheese Festival" Node*: this is the same node as in the top half of the diagram; and
- A *"Should I go to the Milk Festival" Node*: omitted in the diagram for simplicity/brevity
- A *"Should I go to the Bacon Festival" Node*: also omitted for simplicity/brevity

The outputs (Yes/No decisions) from these 3 perceptrons feed, as inputs, into the lone Layer 2 node. **Given my example here, what is an example of a Layer 2 node decision that illustrates this concept of "feature hierarchy" and/or the author's statement that deeper layers can make more complex/abstract decisions?**

Comment: You should take a look at this [well written blog post by Christopher Olah](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/)

Comment: Thanks @jorgenkg (+1) but I believe the only thing that paper/author states w.r.t. my question is "*With each layer, the network transforms the data, creating a new representation...*" Any idea as to how these "new representations" correlate with the more complex/abstract decisions that deeper layers are capable of making? Thanks again!

Comment: Layers are only capable of morphing (stretch/squish) the search space. The more layers you add to your network, the more complex space morphing can be done. The more complex space morphing, the more "complex the decision". Take for instance the "simple example" section of his post. The nonlinear decision boundary can not be modelled with a single layered network.

Comment: No layers are more "smart" than others. They just combine into a conglomerate, making decisions upon the internal representation from the layer below. I would rather say that the final layers are the ones that make the most complex decision - since these decisions are based on the patterns identified by the subsequent network layers.

Comment: Thanks @jorgenkg (+1 again for both) - I am not trying to be difficult here, I think you are just assuming that I'm at a level of competency (w.r.t. ML/DL) that I'm just not at. The concepts you are explaining in your comments above, as well as the paper/blog you provided a link for, all assume a certain level of competency/proficiency that I don't yet have. Please see my update that includes an iron-clad example of what I'm struggling to understand. If you can provide a concrete extension of this example, that should probably help turn all the lightbulbs on. Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb so if we use your Cheese Festival example, the initial perceptron can take in, say, three variables to determine whether it should go the festival or not. One is weather, but what kind of weather? If it's rainy, say, will it stay rainy all day, or get sunny later? Would we prefer to go when it's sunny, or are cheese festivals more fun in the rain? 

These are examples of more complex decision-making on the part of the perceptron/s.

Comment: The second layer takes in the results of the first, and can model itself on these. So the first layer perceptron says to the second: "Hey, the overall weather is sunny". It can't do much more than that, since it's only one perceptron. But the second perceptron (likely many more in a real world situation, actually) can take that assessment and say: "The overall weather is sunny, but it will change to rainy later in the day based on x". And so the network continues, able to do more the deeper it goes

Comment: Thanks @BHouwens (+1 for both) but I just need a wee bit more clarification here. My example above shows 4 neurons that are (essentially) making 4 distinct decisions: (1) Should I go to the Cheese Festival, (2) Should I go to the Milk Festival, (3) Should I go to the Bacon Festival, and (4) ??? some other decision. **Are you saying that my understanding of 1 neuron per decision is incorrect?!?** It sounds like you are saying that, with multiple neurons/layers, there is still only 1 decision being made, but just now we can let multiple neurons handle many more factors/inputs?

Comment: No, sorry, I meant only in terms of the first decision. I narrowed the example for brevity. So you could represent those 4 decisions as 4 separate perceptrons in the first layer, right? The second layer, though, might have 2 more for each perceptron in the first layer (so the second layer now has 8 perceptrons)

Comment: So the first decision, "should I go to the cheese festival?", is handled not only by the perceptron in the first layer, but also its chained perceptrons in the second layer, and _their_ chained perceptrons in the third, etc, etc. all the way until you get to the output node. At that point the "line" or "chain" of reasoning for each of the original 4 decisions are compared, and the winner is the festival we're going to

Comment: Ahhh, thanks @BHouwens (again +1 for both) **now we're starting to get somewhere**, thanks for your willingness to speak my naive "Cheese Festival" language! So does this mean that, with classification problems, each element of the input data (the feature vectors) represents a different class/possible outcome? Meaning, if my 4 choices that I'm trying to decide between are: Cheese Fest, Milk Fest, Bacon Fest or Beer Fest, that each neuron in the input layer (Layer 1) will represent one of those 4 classifications/choices?

Comment: It can be I suppose. Typically, in a supervised situation, your inputs wouldn't be the class/output but rather the input data itself, with the class added on the output node so that the network can work out for itself how to get from input node to output node and the desired class.

Comment: So in our example, you would give the network data on all the times you went to the 4 festivals before. What was the weather like? Were there lots of people? These are your inputs. And you're telling it the outputs (festival we went to before) and letting it work out the in between bits. Then in future, when it's been "trained", we just give it the inputs and it will supply us with the festival we should go to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea of multi layered networks is that each layer adds some amount of abstraction. The 2nd layer itself has the same structure as the 1st layer, therefore it cannot really make more complex decisions on its own. But it can build upon the abstractions (outputs) created the 1st layer.

I like to add that this statement is quite a bit idealized. In practice, it is often difficult to understand what exactly the inner layers do.

In your example, the decision made by the 2nd layer node could be "Should I go to a festival?"

Comment: Thanks @Frank Puffer (+1) - I appreciate this answer. Please see BHouwens' last comment above, where he/she states "*At that point the "line" or "chain" of reasoning for each of the original 4 decisions are compared, and the winner is the festival we're going to*". To me, this contradicts with what you're saying here, which is that the Layer 2 decision is whether or not to go to *any* festival. Can you clarify for me here? Which decision is Layer 2 making (I know this is a hypothetical/arbitrary example): **(a)** which festival to go to, or **(b)** whether to even go to any festival or not?

Comment: @smeeb: In principle both (a) and (b) are possible, but a cell usually has only one output. So for (a), the different festivals must somehow be encoded in the output value, like x<=1/3 => cheese, 1/3<x<2/3 => Milk, x>=2/3 => bacon, assuming an output range between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are visualization of layers in between in deep network.
http://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html

In nutshell each new layer can recognize more complex patterns by looking for pattern in previous layers, and last one have many shapes of desired classes (antz, flowers, cars etc).
Example:

1. first layer detect edges, textures - stuff you can do with photoshop filters
2. second can detect simple shapes based on edges (squares, circles, lines etc) and more complex textures.
3. more complex figures based on shapes from step 2
4. detect shapes closest to target classes

Thats also explains why using pertained models(VGG16/18, AlexNet etc) and switching top levels makes sense. Instead of spending weeks on training full netowork.